# If $A$ is a non-diagonalizable operator then there exists a sequence of diagonalizable operators $A_i$ which converges to $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let $A \in \mathcal H,$ where $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space of dimension $n.$ If $A$ is a non-diagonalizable operator then there exists a sequence of diagonalizable operators $A_i$ which converges to $A.$
To prove this I was trying to prove that if $\lambda_1 , \ldots , \lambda_m$ are distinct eigenvalues of $A.$ And algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_i$  is $k_i$ then for an operator $A_{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\ldots,\varepsilon_{n-m}}$ converges to $A$ such that $\lambda_1,\lambda_1 + \varepsilon_1, \ldots, \lambda_m + \varepsilon_{n-m}$ are distinct eigenvalues of the matrix. But how can I show this.

Comment: The spectral norm is equivalent to any norm , because we are in finite dimensions, and the spectral norm is converging to $0$ because we've chosen our eigenvalues that way, is it not?

Comment: I think the matrices don't necessarily converge to $A$, take e.g. $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, A_{\varepsilon_{1},\varepsilon_{2}}=\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon_{1}&0\\0&\varepsilon_{2}\end{pmatrix}$$ Maybe another idea would be to look at the characteristic polynomial. The set of those matrices with $n$ *distinct* eigenvalues is the non-vanishing set of a polynomial, i.e. the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of a general $n\times n$ matrix.